# Border rendering issue in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, border

I'm having the weirdest issue in IE (7, specifically) when implementing CSS borders. I first noticed this a few months ago.

The CSS is literally this: `#donate {border:1px solid #299ae5;}`

As you can see from the attached image, both of these screenshots were taken in IE7, from the same website, different pages - same template file. It's like the border has a "tail" in the bottom left corner.

[image]

Does anyone have any insight about this???

Edit: Here is the HTML (although I've seen this also on random sites in IE7 recently on input fields as well)

```
<li><a href=""><span>Donate</span></a></li>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
li { display: inline; }
li a { color: #fff; display: block; float: left; margin-right: 8px; padding-right: 8px; line-height: 1.2em; }
li a span { background: url(bg-gradient.png) repeat-x 0 0; border: 1px solid #299a35; padding: 1px 5px 2px 4px; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Needs more context - what kind of an element is this? Can you show the HTML to go with it?

Comment: Are you applying any margins or padding to the element?

Comment: hehehe. Wow, that's horrible! But if this is an IE7-specific issue, then to be honest, I'd just ignore it -- the remaining IE7 users are used to sites looking rubbish in their browser, and this is hardly the worst rendering issue ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use display:inline-block...the only other thing I'd change is making the anchor the button rather than the span. here's a quick example http://jsfiddle.net/3x4fR/2/

Answer (score 0):

Does giving the `li a span` element the `display: block;` declaration do the trick? It may be having trouble applying vertical padding to an inline element.

Comment: Or a zoom:1 to trigger hasLayout?

Comment: Adding display:block; to the span should do the trick. And your padding on the span should take effect.

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle makes testing stuff easy.

If you don't need the span get rid of it if not try *zoom:1 or some other way to give 'hasLayout' to the element. see example here  http://jsfiddle.net/ShaggyDude11/zbZr8/3/